# How to create a method that runs before router method in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Loopback 4 Framework is used.

How to I create `@authentication_control()` method to use before router method.
If it returns true then we get router's answer.
If it return false then we get HTTP 401.

What I want is as pseudo :

```
// if authentication_control is true
// then get answer ({ok:1})
// if authentication_control is false
// get 401

@authentication_control()
router.post('/authenticated_link', (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ ok:1 });
});

authentication_control() {
    let token_key = getTokenKey(); // from Authorization header

    /* checking the user has permission to access this url */
    return checkAllowed(url, token_key); // true or false
}
```

How to create these method's correct way ?

Comment: Is this for express?

Comment: Actually, I use this in loopback 4 framework with TypeScript. So, no, not express.

Comment: you can use `interceptors`, https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Interceptors.html